# How to correctly define activities and intents to behave as desired?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a 'list' activity which starts an 'article' activity when clicked.
I also have push notifications which opens the 'article' activity directly.

I changed the back button behavior in the 'article' activity to start the 'list' activity, when coming from a notification so that the user will go back to the article list.

The problem is when the app is already opened in the background and I open a notification - it just brings it back to front. 
What I want to achieve is open the right article when clicking a notification and going back to the 'list' activity, without having the possibility the the list activity will be open twice.

I tried to separate the 'article' task and create new task in the notification intent but then it would open separate 'list' activities when opening multiple notifications and clicking back.

What is the correct way to define the activities' tasks and intent flags to achieve my goal?

EDIT:
Manifest part:

```
<activity android:name="ListFeed" android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
        android:taskAffinity="com.app.MyTask"></activity>
        <activity  android:name="Article" android:launchMode="standard" android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout" android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:taskAffinity="com.app.MyTask"></activity>
```

Notification intent:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Article.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Post your manifest, and show the code you use to create the PendingIntent for the notification.

Comment: Posted as edit to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i got from your question is that
1) you  have listActivity A

2) ArticalActivity B.

i) And first you want to open Activity A whenever back from B, Correct? for that you can use `dispatchKeyEvent`, listen to Back button event and start activity A. or by using below code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

ii) you want to open only single instance of Activity A(list). for this you can basically use 
 `launchMode` in Activity A's Manifest declration as `singleInstance`.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

you can read [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for launch mode

let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: Please don't use singleInstance. This is the wrong solution for this problem. singleInstance is for HOME-screen replacements.

Comment: ok, There is a tag called android:excludeFromRecent = "true" use this tag into your article activity's manifest declaration. Try with this. and let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks @Ankit! It seems to solve the problem. I do want it to appear in the "recent apps" list. Now this activity can't be returned to from the "recent apps". Is there an alternative?

Comment: i think you are talking about , if you press home button on Article activity and again open your app from recent this activity should be visible. Am i correct? this should be current behavior as still your activity is not killed yet.

Comment: No, the problem is not solved yet as the app do appear in the recents but when clicking it, it would return to the 'list' activity instead of to the 'article', which was open last. I guess this is because of the excludeFromRecents. What I want is to start a new article activity for any article pendingIntent (notifications) and return to the same instance of the list. The last part works now, but not the first.

Comment: You should actually, override onResume method, check which article should be shown and show it, remove exclude from recent tag. In this way you can basically check every-time your article activity getting opened.

Comment: No way to open a new activity instead of this workaround??
I have other things in my onCreate that would require some more changes in order to updated the same activity.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are playing around with launchModes and excludeFromRecents and this isn't a good thing. The standard behaviour of Android should do pretty much what you want.

To verify this I've created a simple 3-activity application that contains a MainActivity, a ListActivity and an ArticleActivity. I'm not using any non-standard launch modes and I'm not setting any Intent flags (except in `onBackPressed()` see below). The Main Activity creates and posts a notification to display a specific Article. The MainActivity starts the ListActivity. Each element of the ListActivity starts an Intent for the ArticleActivity and passes some information in EXTRAS so that the ArticleActivity knows which article to display.

In order to have the behaviour you described (ie: returning from the ArticleActivity to the ListActivity after starting the app from a notification, even if the app was not running), I've done what Ankit has suggested (ie: override `onBackPressed()` in ArticleActivity) like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Return to ListActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    // Finish this activity (in case the ListActivity wasn't already in the stack)
    finish();
}
```

I used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` because this will **not** recreate the ListActivity if it already exists in the activity stack (ie: it will go back to the same instance).

I had to add the `finish()` call, because if the app was not running in the background and the user started it from the notification, the ListActivity would be created and put **on top of** the ArticleActivity. Then when the user pressed "back" to leave the ListActivity, the ArticleActivity would be exposed underneath. Adding `finish()` here makes the ArticleActivity go away so that pressing "back" from the ListActivity goes back to wherever it came from.

If you want me to send you the code, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with with ListActivity was solved. The only remained problem was with re-opening the Article Activity with a new intent. Solved it with the onNewIntent